# Amazon EC2 Micro Instance - Public DNS Not Accessible

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have created a micro instance with Ubuntu OS at Amazon EC2. But I am not able to access public DNS even after installing LAMP Server.

At my apache.conf I can see(no document configuration id available in there) --

```
# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include sites-enabled/
```

Inside **sites-enabled** I have two files -- **default** & **default-ssl**.

Default contains

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

My **apache2** is running at server & **/VAR/WWW/** contains a *index.php* file, where I have written some dummy code for testing.

I tried browsing about it & read somewhere to add a rule in INBOUND for DNS with source `0.0.0.0/0`. That also I did, but still when I am trying to access the public DNS it comes "This webpage is not available".

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by adding HTTP rules in security group of the instance.

Note :- Got help from **##aws** IRC channel.